# How do I grab the selected item from a drop down list in meteor (lookback:dropdowns)

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, meteor, coffeescript

**Explanation**

I am making a small web app to manage some students during a mentorship and when they sign up on the web I want to set who their mentor(s) will be. I am using meteor to accomplish this and have installed [lookback:dropdowns](https://lookback.io/blog/crafting-meteor-dropdowns) to have reactive DDLs (Drop Down Lists) populated with some names. *Note: the DDL actually works and populates names as expected. **This is not the issue.***

**Question**

How do I know the value the user has selected in the DDL so I can change the text on the button so the admin knows what they have selected as they move across the page as well as use the selection to manage the students later on?

**HTML**

```
<template name="aTemplate">
...some stuff up here thats not important..


<td class="text-center vertical-align">{{#dropdownTrigger name="undergraduateDDL"}}<button id="undergraduateID">Select</button>{{/dropdownTrigger}}
        {{#dropdown name="undergraduateDDL"}}<ul>
        {{#each Undergraduates}}
          <li role="menuItem"><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>{{/dropdown}}</td>

...some more DDLs that would behave the same as the one above and some other stuff..
</template>
```

**CoffeeScript (helpers and event listeners etc..)**

```
Template.aTemplate.helpers(

  Undergraduates: ["Some Student"]

  hasInvites: ->
    getInvites = Invites.find({invited: false}, {fields: "_id": 1, "invited": 1}).count()
    if getInvites > 0 then true else false

  invites: ->
    Invites.find({invited: false}, {sort: {"requested": 1}}, {fields: {"_id": 1, "inviteNumber": 1, "requested": 1, "email": 1, "invited": 1}})


)

Template.aTemplate.events(
...some stuff about invitations and email requests..
)
```

*If you're interested, Im using a template from [Meteor Chef](http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/adding-a-beta-invitation-system-to-your-meteor-application/).*

**My Attempt**

I decided not to post the code I attempted since it didn't work anyway and there is probably someone that knows more about what they are doing. Meteor is relatively new to me, just a few months and I'm not a full time dev so I have to learn everything here or on docs.

I will say that I did try to do a script in the html with the dropdowns.get(name) from the lookback docs but I don't think that was the intention of that method (I misunderstood the doc probably). If I can get this to work I will be able to also separate the DDLs into separate templates to manage them independently (add and remove names from the app etc..)

If more information is required please let me know!

*Thank you in advance for helping me figure this out. I know that the students and mentors will all appreciate this web app and thus appreciate your help getting it to work :)*

**Edits (My new code):**

**HTML**

```
<template name="UGMentors">
  {{#dropdownTrigger name="UGMentorsDDL"}}
    <button>{{this.buttonText}}</button>
    {{/dropdownTrigger}}
    {{#dropdown name="UGMentorsDDL"}}
    <ul id="selector">
    {{#each Undergraduates}}
      <li role="menuItem"><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/dropdown}}
</template>
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
Template.UGMentors.helpers(
  Undergraduates: ["Some Student"]
)

Template.UGMentors.created = ->
  @data.buttonText = 'Assign'
  return


Template.UGMentors.events(
    'click #selector': (event, Template) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        #Get the value of the selected text
        selected_value = $(event.target).text()
        alert("Undergraduate: " + selected_value)
        Template.data.buttonText = selected_value
        alert("I made it past line 16!")
        return
)
```

Note: The only thing that doesn't work with this code is updating the button text; back to the original problem. The two alerts in the CoffeeScript work but the Template.data.buttonText = selected_value doesn't actually change the button text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the the issue without having to deviate from the the lookback:dropdown layout at all. It seems I am just not that familiar with jQuery. At any rate I will post my code here for more to see.

**HTML**

```
<template name="UGMentors">
  {{#dropdownTrigger name="UGMentorsDDL"}}
    <button id="UGMButton">{{this.buttonText}}</button> <!-- add an id to the button -->
    {{/dropdownTrigger}}
    {{#dropdown name="UGMentorsDDL"}}
    <ul id="selector"> <!-- The selector is actually the ul -->
    {{#each Undergraduates}}
      <li role="menuItem"><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/dropdown}}
</template>
```

**CoffeeScript Controller**

```
#Populates the DDL 
Template.UGMentors.helpers(
  Undergraduates: ["Some Student"]
)

#Creates the button with default text 'Assign'
Template.UGMentors.created = ->
  @data.buttonText = 'Assign'
  return

#Change to click instead of select (because I am no longer using <select></select>)
Template.UGMentors.events(
#Most of this is from @Flanamacca 
    'click #selector': (event, Template) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        #Get the value of the selected text
        selected_value = $(event.target).text()
        #Below is how I actually changed the button text
        $("#UGMButton").html(selected_value);
        return
)
```

Everything works now!

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected value from a template item - you can use jQuery to help massively.

One easy way to change the text on your button: Have the value set to a value within the template

```
<template name='buttonDropdown'>
  <button>{{this.buttonText}}</button>
  <select id="selector">
    <option value=''>Select an undergrad</option>
    {{#each Undergraduates}}
      <li role="menuItem"><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

Template.buttonDropdown.created = function() {
  this.data.buttonText = '';
}

Template.buttonDropdown.events({
  'change #selector': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the value of this item
    var selected_value = $(event.target).val();
    template.data.buttonText = selected_value;
  }
});
```

Using this approach, everything is bound very tightly into the template and won't leak anywhere else.